# Why is the fs (filesystem) being deleted in the cloud foundry app hosted on IBM Cloud?

Tags: node.js, rest, deployment, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

So I hosted my backend (RESTful API) as a cloud foundry resource in IBM Cloud. The backend dir looks something like this

```
controllers
models
middlewares
pdfs
public
routes
...
```

In my code, I am sending back the pdfs using nodejs fs module, here's the code snippet,

```
  module.exports.viewDocument = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { docId } = req.params;
  const doc = await Docs.findById(docId);
  const file = fs.createReadStream(doc.path);
  const contentType = mime.contentType(path.extname(doc.name));
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachement; filename=${doc.name}`);
  file.pipe(res);
};
```

The code works fine for a few days. But then the application crashes whenever I try to download any pdf (from the frontend app which is built in React). The error logs in IBM Cloud is

```
at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:115:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'pdfs/Semester V/Applied Operating System/aos.pdf'
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
events.js:174
```

Why is this happening? Is the pdfs folder being deleted overtime? It's very strange cause downloading the pdfs work perfectly fine in the beginning (maybe like for a few days).

Comment: Are the files part of what you push with the app?

Comment: Yes, they are.
If there weren't, they shouldn't have worked at all. But in fact, they do work for some days, but then after a few days it stops working and gives the error stating that the folder was not found.

Comment: once it starts to fail, does the backend eventually recover?

Comment: If the files are pushed up with your application then they shouldn't ever change. Those files are fixed as part of the application bits, and when your application is staged/built they are combined with software to run your app (like Node.js) to make a droplet. The droplet is not changed once it has been created. Thus if you start/stop/restart/crash the app you always get the same droplet. The only way the droplet changes is when you restage or push new code.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind that would describe the behavior you're seeing is if you are writing files to the local file system. The local file system is ephemeral and scoped to the lifetime of the application instance. Thus if the app instance restarts for any reason, intentional or unintentional, it will have a new fresh file system. If you were writing files to the local file system then they would be gone. See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#filesystem.

Comment: You can check `cf events` to see if your app is crashing or restarting for some reason around the time that your files disappear. It is possible that your app could be restarted for some backend maintenance reason as well, that may or may not add an entry into `cf events`.

Comment: Yes the backend recovers, but if i try to download any of the pdfs, it crashes again and recovers within a minute or so. @Powell Quiring

Comment: Daniel Mikusa, thanks I think you are right. The problem may be the local file system. Also what is the alternative to local file system ?